# MySQL trigger alter second table on a specific row

Tags: mysql

I created a trigger like:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `update_tb2` AFTER UPDATE ON  `table_1` FOR EACH ROW 

IF new.parameter =  'param1' 
    THEN UPDATE table_2 SET table_2.input =  '10' WHERE table_2.key =  '0';    
END IF ;
```

It works as expected, when I update any row in the table_1 the one with key=0 in the other table is updated.
Since there is a field key in both tables, I want to update in the second table to row who has the same key of the updated row in table_1. I can't figure out how to use table_2.key inside the IF block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the new or old keyword (in case you change the key value, you may want to use one or the other). It let's you access all the values from the record that was updated on table_1:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `update_tb2` AFTER UPDATE ON  `table_1` FOR EACH ROW 

IF new.parameter =  'param1' 
    THEN UPDATE table_2 SET table_2.input =  '10' WHERE table_2.key =  new.key;    
END IF ;
```

You can see an example on this [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d5316)

Comment: Wow really thank you!!! I am new with triggers and so I've not confidence with NEW/OLD parameters, I was trying to specify table_1 instead of NEW !!! 
Really thanks again

Comment: @user1638466. Was something wrong with my answer, for you to change the accepted answer?

Comment: no! I was trying to accept both and then I clicked the other!

Comment: Eheh. Ok. You can only accept one, but if you feel that more than one answer are valid, you can upvote all of them.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `update_tb2` AFTER UPDATE ON  `table_1` FOR EACH ROW 

IF new.parameter =  'param1' 
    THEN UPDATE table_2 SET table_2.input =  '10' WHERE table_2.key =  old.key;
END IF ;
```

Comment: The browser loaded first the second answear! So I used it. Thank to you too ;)